# How to apply this command to subfolders?

Tags: windows, batch-file, bzip2

```
bzip2.exe -z compressfolder/*.*
```

How should modify it so that it will do its job to sub-folders of *compressfolder*?

Answer (score 1):

You'd better to use "find" utility, however I'm not shure it is available on windows under posix environment.

However:

```
find compressfolder -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 bzip2 -z
```

This command on any *nix system will find each regular file under "compressfolder", and will run "bzip2 -z" for each of the files. If you are using cygwin or mingw (as I suppose), it should work on windows also.

Comment: `find` works fine on Windows, too. It might have a different syntax from the command found on a UNIX-based system, but it's still there. No installation of CygWin required.

Comment: @Cody: The `find` that's included in Windows is more akin to `grep`.

Comment: it did not work. also I've tried this one find compressfolder -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 bzip2 -z. Even it did not not compressed the files under compressfolder.

Comment: On windows to get this code working, you should also have "xargs" utility, I don't sure you have it.

Answer (score 1):

This will compress every file under compressfolder, recursively:

```
for /r .\compressfolder %%a IN (*.*) do bzip2 -z %%a
```

The `for /r` will recurse into each subfolder of .\compressfolder.  `%%a` holds each file specified by `*.*`, and the part following `do` runs `bzip2` on each file.  The above examples assumes you'll run this from the parent folder to the compressfolder.  Place the line in a batch file, eg. bzip2all.bat and run it.